# How make use of the Voice API to make calls using Huawei 3g Modems?

Tags: macos, cocoa, api, telephony, 3g

Some Huawei 3g modems like mine (E1752) has ability to make and receive calls. I believe onboard there is PCM channel that can be used while making or receiving the calls but I do not have any more information on that.

I am using their app called the Mobile Partner which is a fairly complete app which supports making and receiving calls. But I want to build my own app which will run on Mac OS X. But I am not able to locate any documents detailing the Voice API and the onboard PCM channel. If anybody is aware of this please let me know.

[image: Mobile Partner app with support for Voice Calls]

Comment: can you please help me in understanding your answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Voice is implemented as follows:- Your Modem registers total of 5 devices.The audio is sent through the serial port named "Huawei Mobile Connect - Application Interface".

Format of voice (in|out) data:

```
  wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
  nChannels = 1;
  nSamplesPerSec = 8000;
  nAvgBytesPerSec = 16000;
  nBlockAlign = 2;
  wBitsPerSample = 16;
  cbSize = 0;
```

Block size of voice data in ReadFile or WriteFile operations (for COM port) must be set in **320** bytes. After each ReadFile must be WriteFile operation (in other choice buffers will be overflow and modem will restart after some time). Sample:

```
//   BlockSize - size of buff for wave in|out operations (in my case 320*4 bytes)

   while (!bAllRead) {
    if (cInfo->hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
     SetVoiceClosed(cInfo);//exit from thread
     return 0;
    }

    BOOL isRead = ReadFile(cInfo->hCom, cInfo->Header[counter].lpData + currBlocLength, 320, &nActualRead, &cInfo->o);
    if (isRead || (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING && GetOverlappedResult(cInfo->hCom, &cInfo->o, &nActualRead, TRUE))) {
     if (nActualRead > 0) {
      // обратка
      nActualWrite = 0;
      int nActualWriteAll = 0;
      BOOL isWrite = WriteFile(cInfo->hCom, CurrBuffPtr + currBlocLength, nActualRead, &nActualWrite, &cInfo->oVoiceOut);
      while (isWrite || (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING && GetOverlappedResult(cInfo->hCom, &cInfo->oVoiceOut, &nActualWrite, TRUE))) {
       nActualWriteAll += nActualWrite;
       if (nActualWriteAll >= nActualRead)
        break;
      }
      currBlocLength += nActualRead;
      if (currBlocLength >= BlockSize)
       bAllRead = true;
     }
     else {
      Sleep(25);// wait for voice data (resync)
      PurgeComm(cInfo->hCom, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
     }
    }
    else {
     bAllRead = true;// there are no active call
     PurgeComm(cInfo->hCom, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    }
   }
```

Something like that))). I do not find any useful info in Internet, so all that recommendation based on my experiments. I hope that was useful.

PS: I hope wave in|out operations will not be a problem for you.

PS2: Sorry for my English, I'm from Ukraine.

Comment: Wow that would be great. There is a lack of documentation around this and I think reverse engineering is the only way forward :(

Comment: Hi, You can simply pass the Audio COM port as "file" for input to FFMPEG(ffplay) and it plays fine. Settings are 1 channel, 16 bit signed little endian and 8kHz. You can implement it in the same way in a app.

Comment: hi sai can please help me in understanding your code.