# Voice commands for Huawei GSM/UMTS usb dongles?

Tags: usb, voice, gsm, modem, dongle

I am trying to find out how to use voice functions with a HUAWEI E173 dongle in linux.

My dongle is voice enabled (voice works with the windows application).
I can check the voice activation in linux using the AT^CVOICE? command.
This tells me how the raw audio stream should be organized.

From question [How make use of the Voice API to make calls using Huawei 3g Modems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367864/) I understand that the idea is to
send commands on ttyUSB2 while passing raw audio data on ttyUSB1.

I also understand that stack overflow user https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043421/sai-chaitanya has voice working in Ubuntu in this way, so that this should indeed be the right approach.

What is completely unclear to me is how to dial out voice calls, to check if someone is calling and to answer voice calls.

Can anyone provide some clue or some pointer on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To do those, you need to use AT commands on the same interface as the one you entered the AT^CVOICE? command.

For example, dialing a certain number (+1 234 567 8888 in this case):

```
ATD+12345678888;
```

You see an incoming call on the terminal with the "ring" or "RINGING" indication. You can use 'ATH' to hang up or 'ATA' to answer.

Read more about AT commands, also called the Hayes command set here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set