# IS there any Huawei API (For Huawei e173 dongle)

Tags: c#, api, dongle

Is there any API for Huawei Dongles(Huawei e173 dongle) I just want to send and receive voice data througt dongle.AT commands will dial the call but can get the voice. I'm using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such api that I know of. You can make calls using the ATD command but the voice doesn't come through it, you must implement your own voice listener. If you are building your own such system I think [this](http://codestudioblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/episode-2-answering-machine-at-commands-and-gsm-modem-interaction/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367864/how-make-use-of-the-voice-api-to-make-calls-using-huawei-3g-modems) might help you.