# Voice call using 3g modem

Tags: c#, voice, phone-call

I am working with 3g modem for voice call. Finding difficult to exchange voice in/out from system to modem, i got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367864/how-make-use-of-the-voice-api-to-make-calls-using-huawei-3g-modems) but not able to understand answer code. I am working with c#.

As lots of content is available online to dial calls using at commands but nowhere explained how to exchange voice between modem and PC speaker & mic. It has been explained that in huawei modem one port is available for at commands which is working perfectly fine for me and second port is available for exchanging voice, which i am not able to understand.

I am not finding any way to move forward.

Comment: Why negative vote if there any answer which is not completely understood. Can not be reasked?

Comment: If I understand your question; you are asking for someone to go look at the earlier question, understand the answers, and translate that C++ answer to C# for you. Its probably why you got a downvote. You need to put the effort to post a minimal, repeatable and verifiable code sample so that other programmers can clearly see what you are asking in order to bring their experience in to help you.

Comment: You may be interested in checking out the [how to ask documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not hesitate to edit your question.

Comment: @John-Philip question edited kindly check once.